# Paraboloidal Coordinates

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

How would one find the transforms for paraboloidal coordinate systems. ie) I want to find $x,y$, and $z$ in terms of other variables so that I can use the Jacobian to find the differential volume.

The paraboloid in question is $z = 16 - x^2 - y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [cylindrical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system)
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos \theta \\
y &= r \sin \theta \\
z &= z
\end{align}
then
$$
z = 16 - r^2
$$
and
$$
\frac{D(x,y,z)}{D(r,\theta,z)} = r.
$$
which leads to a pretty easy volume calculation (if top and bottom of paraboloid are simple enough).

Comment: Is that $\frac{D(x,y,z)}{D(r,θ,z)} = r$ notation referring to the Jacobian?

Comment: @CactusBAMF It's the determinant of the Jacobian matrix. Indeed $$dx\,dy\,dz = \left|\frac{D(x,y,z)}{D(r,\theta,z)}\right|\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$ Sorry for the obscure notation. That's how I learned calculus, the Courant style.